# How to run a mpirun command across multiple docker containers on different hosts

Tags: python, docker, mpi, docker-swarm, openmpi

Setup description:

1. N hosts containing an identical mpi enabled docker (openmpi) image.
2. Each host contains a single image

Goal:

- Execute a python script containing a call to mpirun (via subprocess.run) from within a docker container on one of the hosts on all the other hosts such that the processes will be run inside the docker container on the other hosts. For example if I have 3 hosts, the python script would be launched from within the docker container in the first host (the container would have a hostfile containing the ip addresses of the 2 other hosts)

Question1:

- How do I make sure the mpirun command is actually executed inside the docker containers on the remaining hosts
- Would using a docker swarm with a network overlay is the right approach for this setup and how exactly it should be done?
- What ip address should be inside the hostfile inside the launcher docker container (the ip addreses of the other hosts or the addresses of the overlay network)

Comment: Each container must have its own IP address and must be able to access all the other containers without restrictions. Then simply put those IP addresses in your hostfile.

Comment: Ok but suppose I launch the python script that contains the mpirun command from the first host via docker run, shouldn't the remaining containers on the other hosts be running (with a sleep command ?) so that the mpi processes can be started on those hosts?

Comment: By default, MPI uses `ssh` in order to spawn the daemons (that will launch the tasks) on the remote nodes, so you would need to run the `ssh` daemon on the other docker instances.

Answer (score 0):

- One way to do this would be to create a swarm mode replicated job that runs a command. Then, each time you needed to execute a new command, the python script would perform a `docker service update --args <new command>` and the new command would be executed on each job.
- not relevant to this solution
- not relevant to this solution